# Can I prevent function execution using &=?

Tags: c++, operators

Example code follows:

```
bool result;
result = Operation1();
result &= Operation2();
result &= Operation3();
return result;
```

The intention is to ensure that, if any of the functions returns false, the functions that follow are not called. Is this syntax correct or do I need to do `result = result && Operation2();`?

Comment: Do you mean logical "and" rather than bitwise?

Comment: Yes, I do. Added the extra `&` in the end.

Comment: Since there's no `&&=` operator, the question is moot now that you've realised `&=` is bitwise, right?

Comment: I'm still confused. You want to fix all those other `&=` too, right? You aren't suggesting that you'd use bitwise operators interchanged along with boolean operators?

Comment: @Steve Jessop Yes, that's right. I wasn't aware that &= was bitwise, not logical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean a logical "and" rather than bitwise (I suspect so, since you're using a `bool`), use short circuiting:

```
result = Operation1() && Operation2() && Operation3();
```

The functions will be evaluated left-to-right until one of them returns `false`, then the rest will not be evaluated.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: Yes, the associativity of the `&&` operator is left-to-right.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: Yes, logical and groups left to right and guarantees left-to-right evaluation (Section 5.14)

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that &= was a bitwise operation. Thanks.

Comment: Short-circuiting wouldn't be very useful if the order of evaluation weren't guaranteed.

Comment: Moreover, short-circuiting is *explicitly* guaranteed by the standard

Answer (score 2):

Short-circuiting version of your code (no need for the result variable as you immediately return it):

```
if (!Operation1()) return false;
if (!Operation2()) return false;
return Operation3();
```

Or, if the expressions are really as short as they are in this sample:

```
return Operation1() && Operation2() && Operation3();
```

If the sample code is not representative and you need the variable for some unstated reason:

```
bool result = Operation1();
if (result) result = Operation2();
if (result) result = Operation3();
return result;
```

Comment: I'd write the last two lines of the first snippet as `return Operation3();`, or `return bool(Operation3());` if there's anything peculiar going on with the return types.

Comment: I'd go either way, depending on the actual code.  A more "table-like" layout is easier to understand in some cases.  In general cases, though, the simpler code is better, and I've updated to include that.

Answer (score 1):

`&` does a bitwise and, so in effect you are trying to `and` all your answers together (true if all three operations are successful, false otherwise). This does not provide short circuit evaluation where `Operation2()` isn't called if `Operation1()` fails, and where `Operation3()` isn't called if `Operation2()` fails.

Comment: @djeidot - in that case my answer is not helpful and Fred Larson's is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your method is that I don't believe `true` has to always end up being the same value.  If one op returned 2, another 4, for example, and you & those together you get 0, or `false`.  Even if they all return `true` I don't know that there's any specific guarantee in the standard that they'll have the same bitwise pattern.  Practically speaking, they probably will...but...?

So I'd stick with the `&&` operator unless you work with integrals and make sure that opX() always returns a certain value for true and another for false such that the `&=` operator is guaranteed to do what you expect.

Furthermore, with `&` you don't get short circuiting.

Comment: "true" is always the same value, so "bool(true & true)" is always true with any other combination of bool values yielding false (i.e. same as &&).  But "bool(true & 2)" and "bool(true & 4)" are indeed both false (at least with either two's or ones' complement).

Answer (score 1):

I generally see this pattern written as:

```
bool result = true;
result = result && Operation1();
result = result && Operation2();
result = result && Operation3();
return result;
```